# Initialise a dataframe where a column references another column

Tags: r

I wonder if there is a way to do:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:3)
df$y = df$x + 5
```

yielding:

```
  x y
1 1 6
2 2 7
3 3 8
```

in one line of code where the `y` column refers to the `x` column? For example:

```
data.frame(x = 1:3, y = self$x + 5)    # doesn't work
```

(I won't accept answers that ignore the `x` column, for example, `data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 6:8` :-))

Comment: `tibble::tibble(x = 1:3, y = x + 5)` works.  A `tibble` will allow you to reference previously created variables, where a `data.frame` will not.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R method that do not need to use external package (e.g. `tibble`).

We can use `outer` to add 5 to each element in `df$x`, then `cbind` the result with `df`.

```
setNames(data.frame(cbind(1:3, outer(1:3, 5, `+`))), c("x", "y"))

# or to expand your code
setNames(cbind(data.frame(x = 1:3), outer(1:3, 5, `+`)), c("x", "y"))

  x y
1 1 6
2 2 7
3 3 8
```

Comment: Thanks :) Doesn't that line need the `df` line from my question as well, meaning it's two lines in total?

Comment: @bjfletcher I've updated my code to make it "one line". It's definitely less elegant than the `tibble` solution

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using `tibble` from `tibble` library. Credit to @DaveArmstrong from the comments.

```
library(tibble)
tibble(x = 1:3, y = x + 5)
```

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
      x     y
  <int> <dbl>
1     1     6
2     2     7
3     3     8
```